# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kube-api-access-fcz9j" : object "default"/"kube-root-ca.crt" not registered

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

I have an on-premise kubernetes cluster v1.22.1 (1 master & 2 worker nodes) and wanted to run jenkins slave agents on this kubernetes cluster using kubernetes plugin on jenkins. Jenkins is currently hosted outside of K8s cluster, running  2.289.3. For Kubernetes credentials in Jenkins Cloud, I have created new service account with cluster role cluster-admin and provided token secret text to Jenkins. The connection between Jenkins and Kubernetes has been established successfully however when I am running a jenkins job to create pods in kubernetes, pods are showing error and not coming online.

Below are the Kubernetes Logs.
[image]

[image]

Jenkins logs
[image]
Has any experienced such issue when connecting from Jenkins master, installed outside of kubernetes cluster?

Comment: did you found some solution to this problem? I stuck too with the same issue.

Comment: Can you share the pod specification in YAML format of one of the pods that Jenkins is trying to create in the cluster? You can get it with the following command: `kubectl get pods -o yaml kube-pipeline-test01-......`

Comment: what happens when you run `kubectl get configmap kube-root-ca.crt` ?

Comment: @Allen, kube-root-ca.crt is same as ca.crt, hence I was not sure what else may be missing from certificate chain, when it says that kube-root-ca.crt is not registered

Answer (score 3):

I understand that rootCAConfigMap publishes the kube-root-ca.crt in each namespace for default service account. Starting from kubernetes version 1.22, RootCAConfigMap is set to true by default and hence when creating pods, this certificate for default account is being used. Please find more info on bound service account token based projected volumes -
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/

To stop creating automated volume using default service account or specific service account that has been used for creating pods, simply set "automountServiceAccountToken" to "false" under serviceaccount config which should then allow jenkins to create slave pods on Kubernetes cluster. I have tested this successfully in my on premise cluster.

Comment: simply set "automountServiceAccountToken" to "false" under serviceaccount config ---- Could you please tell us how to do this?

Comment: found it: edit your serviceAccount and add the line  automountServiceAccountToken: false.

If you created your serviceAccount through a command you need to export it first using command: kubectl get serviceAccount <your_serviceAccount> [-n <namespace> ] -o yaml.

Put that in a file, edit and reapply

source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server

Comment: in my case my pod needs access to the API, if i set "automountServiceAccountToken: false", the pods stop working. i'm still searching for the real root cause of this. running k8s 1.22.3, cert is present in the CM

Comment: @Skullone did you ever find the root cause and if so what was the solution?

Comment: @Blunderchips no, it's not a blocker, it's just spamming in the logs but at the ends the crons are able to work. i'm running 1.22.3, maybe upgrading it at 1.23 will help but i'm not there yet... sorry

Answer (score 3):

Under your pod spec you can add `automountServiceAccountToken: false`.
As described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  ...
```

This will not work if you need to access the account credentials.

Comment: This will not work if you need to access the account credentials.

Comment: That is not really the situation described in the question.

Comment: This is the first questions you see when googling this issue as the error messages are identical. It is important to note the limitations on this potential answer.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for quite a while. For me the problem was more simple.
First, I needed the correct permissions. The role for that serviceaccount needed to be in my case

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: build-autoscaler
  name: autoscaler-pod-read-writer
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods", "pods/exec", "pods/logs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["configmaps", "secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

(in particular, pay attention to pods/exec)

In addition to that, bear in mind that the serviceaccount in the cloud configuration, and the service account for the pod needs to be the same (I was using default in the pod and the SA that I had created for the cloud configuration)

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar issue where our Pods couldn't start because they couldn't find the specified ConfigMap for volume mounting. This seemed to be related to changes in Kubernetes service account token handling, which led us to explicitly set the service account token in the manifest.

#### Solution:

You may need to include an explicit service account token in your Pod spec to fix this issue. Kubernetes documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#service-account-token-secrets) details how service account tokens are managed.

Here is a quick snippet demonstrating this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: my-service-account
  automountServiceAccountToken: false # disable auto-mount
  volumes:
    - name: manual-token
      projected:
        sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              path: "token"
  containers:
    - name: my-container
      volumeMounts:
      - name: manual-token
        mountPath: "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
        readOnly: true
```

We took this approach to make sure the volume mount wouldn't fail due to a missing or late-arriving token. This way, the token becomes an explicit part of the Pod's environment, and the service account can pull it from there.

Hope this solves your issue as it did for us.